# Removing file with history in TFS

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to remove a file with it's history from TFS source control? One of our team members hardcoded his password into a file and now we must remove the file with all it's history so the password cannot be found.

Comment: Why not change the password? It's been compromised now.

Comment: The source is not published yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use it carefully:

First, go to a directory that is mapped to a workspace.

`tf destroy "$/path/filename.xyz"`

I would use the /preview switch first to ensure it is destroying what I expect.

If you've done any branching, you'll want to destroy those, as well.

I have to agree with @MattMitchell... it seems easier to just use a different password (and don't hard code it this time).